# Is this relation normalized?

Tags: sql, normalization

I'm uncertain if I've normalized this relation correctly to 3NF. I have provided the question and my answer on the image below due to the requirement of special characters. Could someone please help me understand if I'm wrong and where I might be making a mistake, or is this done correctly?

[image]

Comment: Is this a homework question from a textbook? I've never seen that notation used before either...looks statistical?

Comment: @Twelfth, This notation is actually from a pdf my professor handed out. The question is practice to prepare for the final.

Comment: interesting...it's a quickly changing field to be in...but you'll find there is little standardization here, everyone likes things their own way it seems.  Good luck on the final, but don't expect work environments to be actively using this.

Answer (score 1):

My answer would be different. The traditional treatment of repeating groups is to give each row in the group its own copy of the containing row. A suitable primary key is obtained by combining the key of the containing row with the key of the nested relation:

```
1NF: R(A* B C D E* F G)
```

(I'm using * to indicate the primary key.)

From there, splitting partial dependencies off to their own relations:

```
2NF: R1(A* B C D)
     R2(E* F)
     R3(A* E* G)
```

And this result is in 3NF as well.